# How resolve curved image background in windows CE

Tags: windows-ce

I am using PNG type image with transparent background in picturebox control with stretch Mode in Windows CE. But in pocket pc device it shows wrong behaviour. I provide its screen shot below:
[image]

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, ARGB transparency isn't supported in the CF.  You need to change your image and then use ColorKey transparency. [See the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659312/transparency-in-compact-framework) for more links.

Answer (score 1):

looks to me like you have used an alpha type png RGBA, which is not displayable by your code and its converted to RGB so just displays your background colour as one rectangle.
Greg.