# Transparent PNG in .NET CF

Tags: c#, opennetcf, .net-cf-3.5

in Compact Framework transparent PNG's (or any other image format) are not supported. I tought there are ways to achieve this by using OpenNETCF, but somehow I don't get it to work. I want it to behave like in the normal .NET Framework.

Did I miss something on the OpenNETCF or is it also not supported there?

How hard would it be to implement my own Decoder (maybe with Bitmap/Gif instead of PNG).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659312/transparency-in-compact-framework

Comment: @BondaryukVladimir it does not work like this! My question is completely unrelated: I do not want to use a transparency key, I want to have the same functionality as in the .NET Framework. I want to know if there is a framework providing full support of a transparent image on the .NET Compact Framework, and if not then how time-consuming it would be to create such thing.