# How to use transparent image in WinCe 5.0?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Found examples of using transparency with a background image, but this option does not suit me. Since it is assumed that the background will change upon certain actions.

Comment: What programming language are you using? For example C# .NET 2.0 / 3.5 CompactFramework or embedded C++.

Comment: C# 3.5 CompactFramework

Comment: Perhaps add that to the question (along with my assumption of Visual Studio 2008 as well) and we can delete these comments.

Comment: I've added the necessary tags.

Comment: What examples did you try? What happened when the background changed? Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659312/transparency-in-compact-framework ? The more details you provide about what you're trying to achieve, the higher the chance that you'll get an answer that gets you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing as details are light, but hope this is helpful. We use icons (.ico) files with transparency as follows. These just change the background to a single colour. If you need more complex behaviour, then this may not be suitable.

- Add some icons (with transparent backgrounds) to your project. Set the `Build Action` as `Embedded Resource`. In the example below we use an icon called `ico1.ico`.
- Define a structure to hold your icons. Depending on the number of background colours you require, there would be an instance for each icon/colour combination you need. If the number is very large or unknown at design-time then you'll need to create the icons on-the-fly.

  ```
  public struct CacheGraphics
  {
      public Bitmap ico1White, ico1Blue;
  }
  public static CacheGraphics cacheGraphics;`
  ```
- Cache the icons:

  ```
  cacheGraphics.ico1White = new Bitmap(GetIconImage("ico1", Color.White));
  cacheGraphics.ico1Blue = new Bitmap(GetIconImage("ico1", Color.Blue));`
  ```
- Write a helper function which modifies the background colour:

  ```
  private static Bitmap GetIconImage(string szIcon, Color clrBackground)
  {
      // Convert an embedded icon into an image

      // Load icon
      string szImage = ("YOUR-PROJECT.Resources.Icons." + szIcon + ".ico");
      Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      Stream file = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(szImage);
      Icon icoTmp = new Icon(file);

      // Create new image
      Bitmap bmpNewIcon = new Bitmap(icoTmp.Width, icoTmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

      // Create a graphics context and set the background colour
      Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNewIcon);
      g.Clear(clrBackground);

      // Draw current icon onto the bitmap
      g.DrawIcon(icoTmp, 0, 0);

      // Clean up...
      g.Dispose();

      // Return the new image
      return bmpNewIcon;
  }
  ```
- Define a simple alias for each icon:

  ```
  // Alias which goes at the top of any file using icons: using icons = YOUR-PROJECT.CCommon.AppIcons;
  public enum AppIcons
  {
      ICO1_WHITE,
      ICO1_BLUE
  }
  ```
- Write a helper function to return the cached icon on request:

  ```
  public static Image GetCachedIcon(AppIcons eIcon)
  {
      // Return a cached icon image. These icons are cached at application startup.
      Image imgIcon = null;
      switch (eIcon)
      {
          // System Settings > Advanced
          case AppIcons.ICO1_WHITE:
              imgIcon = (Image)cacheGraphics.ico1White; break;
          case AppIcons.ICO1_BLUE:
              imgIcon = (Image)cacheGraphics.ico1Blue; break;
      }

      return imgIcon;
  }
  ```
- Use icon when required:

  ```
  picturebox1.Image = CCommon.GetCachedIcon(icons.ICO1_WHITE);
  picturebox2.Image = CCommon.GetCachedIcon(icons.ICO1_BLUE);
  ```

Comment: AlainD Do not tell me how to fix the bug after a reboot lost the shortcuts from the desktop. So if you install the program in Program Files, the program also disappears. But if the program is installed in the System folder it is stored. But how to ensure that the labels was still not understand.

Comment: @Macro: Windows CE devices have a fixed write-protected segment and a user area. You need to put your own programs and shortcuts in the user area. The desktop is typically NOT a user area and any shortcuts you put there will be deleted on reboot. To get a program to start automatically you can either put it in your `DEVICE-USER-AREA\Start` folder or in the registry at `HKLM\init\LaunchXXX`. This is a separate question to your original one so you'll need to look for answers or ask a different question. Hope that helps.

Comment: AlainD I have created a topic